# An issue with tomcat 9 upgrade

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

We had upgraded our application with tomcat 9.0.30 version. But after upgradation the application response order gets changed and that behavior is only with UNIX/LINUX box, It is working fine with the window(10) machine.
It is quite surprising for me and don’t have any clue to move forward in this direction. Can someone help to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by _"application response order"_?

Comment: I mean to say API response JSON data order. Prior to the tomcat 9 version API response was sorted into alphabetical order. With Tomcat 9 version API JSON responses get changed.

Comment: Tomcat does not serialize data to JSON. You should look into the library that performs the serialization (e.g. Jackson, Yasson, ...).

Comment: agree but the same application war when we deploy in tomcat 7 it gives a response in alphabetical order. Not only that if we used tomcat 9 in the window machine it gives responses in alphabetical order. But when trying into UNIX/LINUX response order does not maintain.

Comment: It sounds like, in some versions and some platforms, you accidentatlly get JSON in the order you want.  But that behavior wasn't guaranteed.  So, as Piotr Karwasz suggested, you'll want to explicitly choose your JSON library, its version, and configure it to always give the sort order you want.  Jackson, for example, is highly configurable.  BTW, upgrades often bring these kinds of little surprises.  Good luck!